# define edges for undirected graph in coq

Tags: coq

So i am trying to define edges in an undirected weighted graph with specific nodes.(in my case, the node is just number). (nat*nat*nat) -> the first two nats represent the two nodes n1,n2, and the last nat represent the edge weight. (edge b/t n1 and n2)
My question is IDK why there is an error.
Below is my code.

```
Definition vertices := list(nat).
Definition edges := list(nat*nat*nat).
Definition Graph := (vertices,edges).

Compute Graph.
Compute edges.


Definition myEdges : edges := [(1,2,2);(1,3,2);(2,3,4)].
```

the error msg pop up on the last command:

error msg:

The term "1" has type "nat"
while it is expected to have type "Type".

Any one could explain and help me??? Thanks a lot!!

Comment: Should `Definition Graph := (vertices, edges)` be `Definition Graph := vertices * edges` instead?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The pair `(1, 1)` is a *value*, and actually just a notation for `pair 1 1`.   It is a term that has type `prod nat nat`, which has an alternative notation `(nat*nat)`.  So `(nat*nat)` is a *type*, not a value.

So if you want to create a *type*, use `*`, and often you also have to explain to Coq that you don't mean `*` for `nat`, but `*` for types, which you do by annotating which scope ("notation context") you want to use; `(nat*nat)%type`.

I guess what you want to do is to define `Graph` as a type, and then you want to create specific graph instances as values with the type `Graph`.

If you want to inspect terms and types, it is useful to do

```
Set Printing All. 
Check (1,2).
```

which prints out the term without any notations.  In this case it prints

```
@pair nat nat (S O) (S (S O))
     : prod nat nat
```

Answer (score 2):

The following works on my computer:

```
Require Import Coq.Lists.List.
Import ListNotations.

Definition vertices := list(nat).
Definition edges := list(nat*nat*nat).
Definition Graph := (vertices,edges).

Compute Graph.
Compute edges.

Definition myEdges : edges := [(1,2,2);(1,3,2);(2,3,4)].
```

Did you forget to include something in your snippet?